# Advanced Problem in Complex Variable Functions & Applications

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, harmonic-functions

I have this question from CVF, I'll add a screen capture since the whole problem is really long:

[image: Screen Capture From Book]

Where $\tilde{x}= x+ r\cos(\theta)$ and $\tilde{y}=y+r\sin(\theta)$

I don't know what this hint is implying, or what I'm supposed to do right now.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic in $D$ it need not be defined on the boundary. Are you assuming that $f$ is continuous in $\overline {D} $?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think the book is assuming it, just not stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is continuous on the closure of $D$ there is some point in the closure where $|f|$ has its maximum value.  Suppose this point $x+iy$ is in the interior. Consider a  closed disk, say of radius $R$, around this point contained in $D$. Use the last inequality in the hint to see that $|f|$ must be a constant in this disk: the integrand on the right does not exceed $M\equiv \max \{|f(z)|:z \in D\}$ so we get $M=|f(x+iy| \leq \frac 1 {\pi R^{2}} \int_{D_R(x+iy)} M dx dy$. This means equality must hold throughout.

We have proved that $|f|$ is a constant in the disk and this implies that $f$ is itself a constant. Connectedness of $D$ now implies that $f$ is a constant on the whole of $D$.

Comment: When you say that the equality must hold throughout, what equality are you referring to?